# Reference string from resx resource in XAML style

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have button style in my Win10 UAP. The style has tooltip.

How do I make this style reference text in resx string resources?

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" >
        ...
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="<string in resx resources>" />

    </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello in UWP it is best to use .resw not .resx. Here is how you can do it with .resw resources:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TextBlock x:Uid="CustomText" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My .resw file looks like:
Name -> CustomText.Text

Value -> This is custom text